# How magento maintain grid values

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to know where and how does magneto store the data to maintain grid filter and mode type. Like I go to listing page and select list mode while displaying five records and then goes to other page of the same site and comeback. It shows me my previous grid mode and records. I display `$_REQUEST`, but doesn't see anything there. Anyone knows how I can get those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento store limit,order,direction in `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')`.
If limit,order,direction is found in REQUEST then new value is set in `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')` .

You can check **getLimit(),getCurrentMode(),getCurrentOrder(),getCurrentDirection()** function in the class

> app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php

Comment: @suman-php-4u Thanks for your response ,I also visite the page toolbar.php before posting the question. but as for i think these run on default listing.but when one override the list module and extend class from Mage_core_Catalog_Block_List than these variables are not accessible.did you know why ?